# Error with matrix listing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to run this program but it has the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Αλέξανδρος/Desktop/1.py", line 12, in <module>
    k=k+C[s]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is below

```
a=0
b=0
s=0
k=0
A = [0 for a in range(1000)]
B = [0 for b in range(1000)]
C = [0 for s in range(1000000)]
while a<=1000:
    C[s]=(A[a]**2+B[b]**2)**0.5
    a=a+1
    s=s+1
    k=k+C[s]
    if a==1000:
        b=b+1
        a=0
if a==1000 and b==1000:
    print (k/1000000)
```

I know that this question is probably duplicated, but I don't know how to solve it, because in the beggining I thought that the error is because C[-1] doesn't exist. But I don't think that is the problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Of course, Python 3.6.4

Answer (score 2):

Because of `a<=1000` you code executes 1,000,001 iterations, but there are only 1,000,000 elements in the list. You made a classical "*off by 1*" mistake.  Change `<=` to `<`.

Indeed, you should be using `numpy` for problems like this.

Comment: Actually, I am on Python 3.6.4

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The loop actually attempts to execute 1000001 iterations (because `a` is reset to 0!).

Comment: nvm, just opened up a shell, this is exactly it. Didn't notice that `a` gets reset to `0`

Answer (score 0):

You are acessing past the array range, but just changing <= to < won't fix it as it will still execute

```
s=s+1
k=k+C[s]
```

in the iteration where s=999999 and it breaks when trying to access C[1000000].

You can easily debug the values on the iteration where it breaks by adding a print:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

a=0
b=0
s=0
k=0
A = [0 for a in range(1000)]
B = [0 for b in range(1000)]
C = [0 for s in range(1000000)]
while a<=1000:
    print("a={:d} b={:d} s={:d}".format(a,b,s))
    C[s]=(A[a]**2+B[b]**2)**0.5
    a=a+1
    s=s+1
    k=k+C[s]
    if a==1000:
        b=b+1
        a=0
if a==1000 and b==1000:
    print (k/1000000)
```

And you will get your culprit:

```
(...)
a=997 b=999 s=999997
a=998 b=999 s=999998
a=999 b=999 s=999999
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./off.py", line 15, in <module>
    k=k+C[s]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Regarding your algorithm, the s=s+1 / k=k+C[s] lines should probably be reversed (you want to accumulate in k the latest C[s] computed, C[s+1] is always 0 as it will only be computed by the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited a little the code (I reversed  s=s+1 / k=k+C[s]), but now I get the same error for the line C[s]=(A[a]**2+B[b]**2)**0.5 (line 11)